# Change background image positioning on different devices

Tags: html, css, resize, background-image, device

I'm wondering how to set my css so that when my device is small enough, a specific part of the background image is what gets shown (not the center of the original image?)

currently my background image is set with

```
background-image: url(*.jpg);
background-position: center;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

right now when you reduce the size, it shows just the center of the image, where i'm looking to show something that's roughly a third from the left of the image.

Is it possible to do this with just css?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do media queries and then background-position:

```
@media(min-width: 768px){
    background-position: 35% 55%; //percentage-based to "absolutely" position
    /*background-position: center left;*/ //Maybe this too

}
```